# Render a HtmlSelectOneMenu with only one entry as readonly inputfield in jsf?

Tags: list, jsf, combobox, tags, custom-component

Well we're trying to render a shitload of lists. Some of them have only one entry and we want them to appear as read only input fields (so users don't get fooled and it's easier to read).
But it seems kinda hard to access the inner selectitems size from outside.
I had my go with overwriting the htmlselectonemenu tag... Is there a different nicer way? Even possible to access it on tag level?

```
/**
 * In case there is only one or less elements in the select list -> set readonly(true)
 */
public class HtmlSelectOneMenuModf extends HtmlSelectOneMenu {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadonly() {
        for (Iterator iterator = getChildren().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Object obj = iterator.next();
            if ( obj instanceof UISelectItems) {
                UISelectItemsi = (UISelectItems) obj;
                if(i.getSelectItems().size() <=1)
                    super.setReadonly(true);
            }
        }
        return super.isReadonly();
    }
}
```

We're chilling on JSF 1.2 btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`fn:length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/length.fn.html).

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.item}" readonly="#{fn:length(bean.items) le 1}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.items}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: learned something new :-) the problem though lies in our implementation, we override UISelectItems and in the getSelectItems() we actually perform the complete resolving of the list, e.g. using drools custom java methods etc. It looks like bad design to implement it on the lowest level, uhm. I'll refactor this as soon as i get some time, thanks.